# Referencing JSON response to POST of form data with jQuery and the Form plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble understanding how to use jQuery and its Form plug-in to access the data returned by an HTTP post operation.

For example, I would like to POST data in a form from a browser, process the data on the server, return a server response (in JSON) to the browser, and display information about that response to the user in an alert -- without rewriting the form.

I thought the following jQuery code would do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajaxFormSubmit').bind('click', function(event) {
        $('#data_entry_form').ajaxSubmit({
            url: "data_entry_ajax",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Success');
                alert(data.save_status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The server returns the following in JSON object:

```
{'save_status': 'OK', 'id_number': 2}
```

But instead of displaying the two alerts over the form and user-entered data, the browser is wiping out the form and displaying the JSON reply.

I thought the "success" value in the options submitted to ajaxSubmit was automatically passed the response received from the server.  I've tried various permutations of passing in arguments to the function body (referring to `data` without passing it in, referring to `responseText` with and without passing anything in), but these don't work either.

I've looked at "jQuery In Action" to try to understand accessing the response to an xhr object and a .ajax() function, but that hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [jQuery $.post()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

```
<script>
// ...
$('#ajaxFormSubmit').bind('click', function(event) {
  $.post(
    'data_entry_ajax',
    $('#data_entry_form').serialize(),
    function(data) {
      alert('Success');
      alert(data.save_status);
    },
    'json'
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, this is still wiping out the browser document and displaying the JSON request.  Maybe the problem is in my HTML.